# Testinfra not seeing nginx when run through Molecule

Tags: python, ansible, molecule

I don't understand what I am missing. I am trying to run a basic test from the documentation to see if my Ansible role deploys and runs nginx. I can login to the VM and verify, but that defeats the purpose of using molecule.

All testinfra and molecule tell me are that the assertion tests failed.

Here is my test code:

```
import os

import testinfra.utils.ansible_runner

testinfra_hosts = testinfra.utils.ansible_runner.AnsibleRunner(
os.environ['MOLECULE_INVENTORY_FILE']).get_hosts('all')

def test_nginx_running_and_enabled(host):
    nginx = host.service("nginx")
    assert nginx.is_enabled
    assert nginx.is_running
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The code you posted is valid, so that means something else is going on here. Could you please share the relevant output?